# Is it true that $f(a,b)=f(a,c)$ whenever $b=c$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How to prove this (true or not)?

> $f(a,b) = f(a,c)$  must hold if $b = c$

**Note:** ***f(a,b)** is a function with **a** & **b*** parameters

thanks

Comment: This should be true if $f$ is well defined

Comment: I have updated your post to LaTeX, please make sure everything is correct and as you meant it.

Comment: what is well defined? i really basic in math

Comment: How can *anyone* refer to this question if we don't have the slightest idea what in the holly word $\;f\;$ is ??

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand your concern about what $f$ is, but I assume that if OP is asking this sort of question, then he/she is probably dealing with a function $f$. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say with your example though; the statement is "show $f(a,b) = f(a,c)$ if $b=c$," not if and only if. Could you clarify?

Comment: It was a matter of language, @blf ...I think. It looks like the OP asks two different things, according to the position of the "if", yet perhaps it is not so. I'm not sure. Anyway, if the question is correctly posted then it is a trivial one: for *any* function, $\;f(a)=f(b)\;$ whenever $\;a=b\;$ , and *apparently* this is what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: by definition, a function takes in some inputs, and produces a *unique* output.

Comment: How do you know $\;f\;$ is supposed to be a function?? And if it is, then is it a one or a two variables functions? What's its definition domain and its codomain...?

Answer (score 0):

See it is a bi variate function that you have given here.
Just think of a 3-D(2 dimentional system of co-ordinate).
Now if a function is a bivariate one then the functional value will have the value on axis which one is mutually perpendicular to the other two axis.
Now you have the equation as f(a,b)=f(a,c).Now we have to prove that the equation can only hold if b=c.
But see can we say anythhing about the functional characteristics like if f(a,b)=f(a,c) then 'b' should be equal to 'c'!
How can anyone conclude it surely without knowing the actual function?
See here I have an example:  f(a,b)= (a^2)+(b^2)  and  f(a,c)= (a^2)+(c^2).
See here,for the first function f(a,b) if we put a=1 and b=1 then the functional value will be 2,fine.If we put in the 2nd function a=1 and c=(-1) then also the functional value is 2 but see here for these two function **b(b=1) is not equal to c(c=-1)** for these two cases **but still the functional value are same!!**
So what do you think my friend.Don't we need the actual characteristics of the function?

Comment: No, we don't.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $\forall$x(x=x), then yes.

Suppose that b=c.

f(a,b)=f(a,b) since we can derive it from substitution and that $\forall$x(x=x).

Now since b=c we can replace just the second "b" by "c" and obtain

f(a,b)=f(a,c).